# Check concat array with Jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I've got a file release.ts with this method:

```
class Release{
public releaseTicketIds(): string[] {
    const tab = [];
    const tab2 = [];
    this.newFeatures.forEach((issue) => {
        tab.push(issue.id);  //["1", "2"]
    });
    this.fixedIssues.forEach((issue2) => {
        tab.push(issue2.id);   //["3", "4"]
    });
    const globalTickets = tab.concat(tab2);
    return globalTickets;
}
}
```

I want to do a test with Jest:

```
test("concat two array", () => {
    // Given
    const array = ["1", "2"];
    const array1 = ["3", "4"];

    // When
    const result = Release.releaseTicketIds();

    // Then
    expect(result).toBe(["1", "2", "3", "4"]);
});
```

I've got this error:

```
Property 'releaseTicketIds' does not exist on type 'typeof Release'
```

I don't wanna change to static ...
What can I do ?

Comment: _I don't wanna change to static_ but you want to invoke it as static?

Comment: Oh ok :/ how can I invoke in public ?

Comment: Create an instance, then invoke it (e.g. `const result = new Release().releaseTicketIds();`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, create an instance, then invoke it:

```
test("concat two array", () => {
    // Given
    const array = ["1", "2"];
    const array1 = ["3", "4"];

    // When
    const result = new Release().releaseTicketIds();

    // Then
    expect(result).toBe(["1", "2", "3", "4"]);
});
```